# When did Apple adopt the JIS keyboard layout as it is now for their MacBook Pros?

Tags: macbook-pro, history

When was the current [JIS (Japanese Industrial Standard) keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_input_methods#Japanese_keyboards) adopted on Macbook Pro's?

The JIS keyboard layout keeps the Roman letters in the English QWERTY layout, with numbers above them:

[image]

This is the JIS layout on a Thinkpad:

[image]

Comment: @TomGewecke the modifier history differences have a historical reason.  British English the keyboard layout it different order/symbols but it isn't completely missing keys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about why apple did or didnt do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding adoption of the JIS keyboard, Apple has sold it for 20 years or so.  This [this note](https://www.fenestrated.net/mirrors/Apple%20Technotes%20(As%20of%202002)/tn/tn1152.html).

Comment: Great find!....